# What exactly happen if I called connect() in Linux

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, network-programming

When I called connect() in linux, I saw that the socket was bound to the ip of the interface related with the default gateway. I mean It seems like to call bind() internally when called connect(). Is it really call bind()?
I tried this with udp socket

Also, If I call connect(), Does it always checks routing table to know that destination ip is valid?

Comment: If I understood you right, I believe you can use `strace` to see what system calls are called when running your program.

Comment: thnak you I try it

Answer (score 0):

> It seems like to call bind() internally when called connect(). Is it really call bind()?

Yes, `connect()` will `bind()` the socket to a local interface and ephemeral port, but only if the socket is not already bound.

> Also, If I call connect(), Does it always checks routing table to know that destination ip is valid?

Not for UDP, no.  `connect()` on a UDP socket merely assigns a static peer IP/port to the socket, nothing more.  If you then try to `send()` on a connected UDP socket, and the destination is invalid, the packet will not be delivered, and `send()` may return an error code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. but when I tried to connect() without any routing information about default gateway, kernel returned error code (101, Network is unreachable). I didn't use any kind of send() like sendto(), send(), sendmsg() etc. So I thought that connect() check routing table.